# How do I return or print an attribute that's a math function between two attributes? Python

Tags: python, object, constructor

I'm very new to Python and have checked the three other posts about this subject but haven't been able to implement them successfully.

Essentially, I'm trying to return the name of the county with the highest voter turnout and the percentage. I can't seem to figure out how to return or print the latter part, as I don't have an attribute for the math portion (voters / population).

I've played around with some things like:

```
def percentage(self, turnout):
  self.turnout = voters / population
```

Sorry if this post does not format correctly — this is all very new! Thanks in advance.

```
class County: 
  def __init__(self, name, population, voters):
    self.name = name
    self.population = population
    self.voters = voters

def highest_turnout(data):

  highest_county = data[0]
  highest_percentage = (data[0].voters / data[0].population)

  for county in data:
    if (county.voters / county.population) > highest_percentage:
      highest_county = county
      highest_percentage = (county.voters / county.population)
  return highest_county.name

  
  # implement the function here


# your program will be evaluated using these objects 
# it is okay to change/remove these lines but your program
# will be evaluated using these as inputs
allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469) # this is an object
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  

result = highest_turnout(data) # do not change this line!
print(result) # prints the output of the function
# do not remove this line!
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply return multiple values:

```
return highest_county.name, highest_percentage
```

In your calling program:

```
best_county, best_pct = highest_turnout(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Could I still use those two variables you listed last even though I hadn't introduced them before?

Comment: If you mean `best_*`, yes, you can use those.  This is how you introduce variables; you give them a value.

Answer (score 1):

What's very cool in python is you can actually just write the following:

```
highest_turnout = max(data, key=lambda county: county.voters / county.population)
```

Here, `highest_turnout` is the county with the highest turnout. What we've done is told python to calculate the maximum of the dataset where the values being compared is `voters/population` ie: the percentage of voters that came. In other words, this does exactly what your `highest_turnout` function does in a single line. You might consider defining a method for your `County` class called `get_turnout()` which just returns the percentage of the population that voted.

Obviously with `highest_turnout` we can write

```
highest_turnout.name
```

and

```
highest_turnout.voters / highest_turnout.population
```

to have the values you seek.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. We had not learned yet about "lambda" but it's clearly the easiest way to find the solution.